# Questions about using matlab to draw contour plots

Tags: matlab, data-analysis, matlab-figure, contour

How to draw contour plots of irregular graphics using matlab？ My code is as follows:

```matlab
figure(11)
[xq,yq] = meshgrid(0:0.1:225, 0:0.1:40);
vq = griddata(gcoord(:,1),gcoord(:,2),uw,xq,yq);
contourf(xq,yq,vq,'ShowText','on','LineStyle','-')
xlabel('Distance(m)','FontName','Times New Roman','FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold');
ylabel('Elevation(m)','FontName','Times New Roman','FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold');
set(gca,'FontName','Times New Roman','FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold');
colorbar
colormap jet
hr=colorbar;
set(get(hr,'Title'),'string','kPa');
% set(hr,'Position',[0.875129310344827 0.17 0.0149999999999999 0.68],'box','off');
box off
```

`gcoord` is data containing x-y coordinates.

I want to get a contour plot shaped like the following：

[image]

But the result of the code is like this:

[image]

How should I modify my code?

Comment: So what is the issue? Is it the aspect ratio or is it the missing data points to the left and right of the triangle bit? It looks pretty similar otherwise. Maybe the color map? The written numbers along the isolines?

Comment: Without the data in gcoord readers cannot reproduce the question. Please supply the contents of gcoord, or enough of it so we can reproduce the distorted image that you need to match the 1st screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

As John BG commented, without your variable data for gcoord we can't replicate your data to test solutions. I'm too new to stackoverflow to post a comment, so I need to submit this as an answer.

My first instinct on this is to try and control the plot using xlim and xtick values. I see in the example that you posted it had several specific xtick values (in increments of 20) and your plot does not. I would check out the MATLAB documentation on how to implement these.

[MATLAB Help on xticks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html)